# What is the probability that at least one head is obtained from the unbiased coin?

Tags: probability, dice

A loaded die is tossed once; if N is the result of the toss, then $P$($N = i$) = $p_i$
,
$i = 1, ..., 6$. If $N = i$, an unbiased coin is tossed independently i times.

What is the probability that at least one head is obtained from the unbiased
coin? Given that at least one head is obtained, what is the probability that N
will be odd?

I know that a loaded die has probabilities 1/21, 2/21,3/21, 4/21, 5/21, 6/21 of showing 1,2,3,4,5,6. But, I am confused as to what $p_i$ is.

Comment: This is not correct -  "a loaded die has probabilities 1/21, 2/21,3/21, 4/21, 5/21, 6/21 ".  Loaded just means not equal probility.  Here $P(N=i)=p_1$, $P(N=i)=p_2$ and so on, where the values of $p_i$ are left as variables in the problem.  Of course, they have to add up to 1.

Comment: So, apart from that, is the question clear to you and you know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You just compute it.  If the die shows $4$, you flip four coins and have $\frac {15}{16}$ chance of getting at least one head.  Multiply that by $\frac 4{21}$ and add all the others.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that a loaded die has probabilities 1/21, 2/21,3/21, 4/21, 5/21, 6/21 of showing 1,2,3,4,5,6. But, I am confused as to what $p_i$ is.

Well now, $p_i$ is the probability that a roll of the biased dice shows face $i$.

It you have been *told* that these are the probabilities for *your* loaded die, then they are the six $(p_i)$ values.   However, if you have *not* been told so, then you *cannot* just *presume* it, and must leave the values as variables.

Now, you know that the probability for at least one head showing among $i$ tosses of an unbiased coin will be: $\mathsf P(H>0\mid N=i)=$ /////.

Where $H$ is of course the count for heads among the tosses of the unbiased coin.

Then, by the Law of Total Probability: $\mathsf P(H>0) = \sum_{i=1}^6 p_i \mathsf P(H>0\mid N=i) = $ /////.

Finally find $\mathsf P(N\in\{1,3,5\}\mid H>0)$ using the definition of conditional probability.

Divide and calculate.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you flip an unbiased coin $k$ times, the chance of getting only tails is $\frac{1}{2^k}$, so the chance of getting heads at least once is $1-\frac{1}{2^k}$.
2. According to the way your die is biased, you have a $\frac{1}{21}$ chance of flipping one coin, $\frac{2}{21}$ of flipping two coins, etc.
3. Therefore, your probability of getting at least one heads is:
   $$\sum_{k=1}^6\frac{k}{21}(1-\frac{1}{2^k})=\frac{1}{21}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{21}\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{21}\frac{7}{8}+\frac{4}{21}\frac{15}{16}+\frac{5}{21}\frac{31}{32}+\frac{6}{21}\frac{63}{64}=\frac{51}{56}$$